# Верно ли употребление слова «прошедший»?

Tags: согласование, причастный-оборот

«..начало ноября ознаменовалось проведением международного Форума и международной конференции, прошедшим в Ливадии.»

Answer (score 1):

Фраза действительно звучит некрасиво. Существительное "проведением" и причастие "прошедшими" конфликтуют. Вариант правки:

***..начало ноября ознаменовалось проведением в Ливадии международного Форума и международной конференции...***

Если же конструкцию менять Вы не хотите, то тогда, на мой взгляд, лучше употребить не "прошедших", а "проходивших".

Comment: Гораздо лучше изменить конструкцию. Но если уж оставлять, то "проведением (мероприятий), **проходивших**"

Comment: Да, конечно! Исправила.